# Select single row with checkbox in sap.ui.table

Tags: sapui5

noobie_sapui5_developer

I am trying select single row of sap.ui.table with checkbox.

There are 2 modes for this table

1. Multi
2. Single

In multi selection mode there are checkboxes for each row and multiple rows can be selected - but I want only a single row to be selected

In single selection mode, it allows only a row to be selected - but there are no check boxes.

How to achieve a table with checkboxes with only one selectable row?

It is possible with sap.m.table, but my requirement is to make it work with sap.ui.table.

Comment: Any particular reason why you need a checkbox in a table where the user is only supposed to select a single value? This goes against common UX conventions (https://www.nngroup.com/articles/checkboxes-vs-radio-buttons/). And the specific selection design suggestions for the sap.m.Table (https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/responsive-table/#selection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Why I wouldn't recommend doing this:*

Checkboxes (`selectionMode="MultiToggle"`) are usually used to signal the user that he's able to select no, one or more options, while radio buttons (`selectionMode="Single"`) tell the user that he's only able to choose one option.

**See:** [material.io](https://material.io/design/components/selection-controls.html#), [nngroup](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/checkboxes-vs-radio-buttons/), [uxplanet-radio](https://uxplanet.org/radio-buttons-ux-design-588e5c0a50dc), [uxplanet-checkbox](https://uxplanet.org/checkbox-and-toggle-in-forms-f0de6086ac41)

In your case, I'd recommend using the `selectionMode="Single"` and either set the `selectionBehavior` attribute to `Row`, `RowOnly` or `RowSelector` ([SelectionBehaviour](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.SelectionBehavior)).

---

As @jasbir pointed out, you *could* use the [rowSelectionChange](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.Table/events/rowSelectionChange) event in order to invoke a function that grabs the index ([getSelectedIndex](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.Table/methods/getSelectedIndex)) of the row that was just selected. You can then call the `setSelectedIndex` function on the `sap.ui.table.Table` and pass it the grabbed index. This will remove previously selected rows and set the currently selected row as selected.

```html
<Table id="yourTableId"
    selectionMode="MultiToggle"
    rowSelectionChange="onSelectionChange">
</Table>
```

And in the controller.

```
onSelectionChange: function(oEvent) {
    var oYourTable = this.getView().byId("yourTableId"),
        iSelectedIndex = oEvent.getSource().getSelectedIndex();

    oYourTable.setSelectedIndex(iSelectedIndex);
}
```

> **Note:** Since the `setSelectedIndex` function triggers a `rowSelectionChange` the above function gets triggered twice (another indicator that this solution isn't intended behaviour).

*Check the SAP Fiori Guidelines for the [sap.ui.table.Table](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/grid-table/) for further information.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use rowSelectionChange event whenever a selection is changed you can unselect other rows and keep the selected one.

Hope this helps

Comment: how to unselect the other rows? Here is what all i tried to do:

Comment: inside rowSelectionChange event i did table.clearSelection() and tried to select the current row. But i couldn't find any method for that.- failed.  Next method - I tried to deselect all other rows except current row with help of table.removeSelectionInterval(), but i couldn't get the table row count for that.